# Curve Fitting Including Convolution in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, deconvolution

I would like to fit two parameters $K_1$ and $k_2$ in the problem 
$f(t)*C_a(t) = C_E(t)$ where $*$ represents the convolution operator and $f(t) = K_1 e^{-k_2 t}$. $C_a(t)$ and $C_E(t)$ are given discrete input data.

I see two alternatives:

- Deconvolve an approximation of $f(t)$ out of $C_E$ using the MATLAB command *deconv* and thereafter use *lsqcurvefit* to fit $f(t)$ to the result of the deconvolution.
- Construct another function $g(t) = f(t)*C_a(t)$ and thereafter perform the curvefitting with *lsqcurvefit* directly with $g(t)$ to minimize  $||C_E(t) - g(t)||_2$.

Can anyone tell if I should expect any difference between the solutions obtained from the different approaches?

Comment: What about a thrid approach in the frequency domain?

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 That is an idea but what do I then do with $C_a$ and $C_E$ who are given vectors in time domain? z-transform everything?

Comment: Transform them and then deal with them just as you would the time-domain vectors, no? I suggest the idea since it would let you multiply rather than convolve, which might makes things easier.